# Optimizing a multivariate quadratic fn

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $D\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where $m\geq n$, and D is full column rank.

I'd like to find $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^m}f(x)$, where $f(x):=\frac{-1}{2}x^T DD^T x+c^T x$.

 I know the answer is: 
$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^m}f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}c^T D(D^T D)^{-2} D^T c & \text{ if } c \in Range(D) \\ 
\infty & \text{ o/w } 
\end{cases}$

But I'd like to justify the case where $c\in Range(D)$.  I found $\nabla f(x)=-D D^T x+c$, which =$\textbf{0}_m$ when $D D^T x=c$, so there are infinitely many x that make $\nabla f(x)=\textbf{0}_m$, so not sure what to do from here.